# Netplan throws an error when attempting to load a config file, provides no details about what the error is

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ethernet, netplan

Doing a clean install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a new machine.  Currently attempting to configure my Ethernet network interface to use DHCP using `netplan`.

My config file, dynamic.yaml, reads as follows:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
```

When I attempt to load this configuration with

```
sudo netplan try
```

I get an error which reads:

```
Error while loading /etc/netplan/dynamic.yaml, aborting.
```

```
sudo netplan --debug try
```

merely prints out "ERROR:Error while loading /etc/netplan/dynamic.yaml, aborting."

Any ideas what the error is?  Or does anyone have any suggestions for how to get netplan to actually specify what the error is?

Comment: The `netplan-try` manual page suggests there's a `--debug` switch: have you tried `sudo netplan --debug try`?

Comment: Merely says the same thing unfortunately

Comment: Does `sudo netplan --debug generate` give any more clues?

Comment: Inspect your file with `od -bc /etc/netplan/dynamic.yaml`. Check for TABs, spaces, End-Of-Line, spurious `^M`, bytes > 128. Didn't we learn from `Makefile` syntactic sensitivity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

netplan is VERY fussy about .yaml file formatting. No tabs, specific indentation, and no extra spaces. Your .yaml looks ok syntactically, but try this variation...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
```

`sudo netplan generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply config

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Comment: Turns out I was using tabs instead of spaces - switching to spaces fixed the issue,  Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema, this answer made me get out my glasses and find the issue in my netplan -- tedious.  Is there a YAML parsing utility (any language) that you know of to find issues programmatically?

Comment: @ToddCurry Check out `yamllint`. It's in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Brilliant, @heynnema -- thank you!  When I googled, I also found yamllint.com, (which may/may not be secure, but)  checks your yaml in a web form.  You have set me on a path to yaml sanity!

Answer (score 1):

Everybody should try `yamllint`. It helps you write a proper formatted yaml file. Install `sudo apt install yamllint`.

Then check your file:

```
yamllint /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
01-network-manager-all.yaml
  1:81      error    line too long (203 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
  1:202     error    trailing spaces  (trailing-spaces)
  2:8       error    syntax error: mapping values are not allowed here (syntax)
```